# Leaflet js cant load map photos

Tags: leaflet, cartodb

I work for a company and my programmer co-workers use leafletjs. Until now the map worked perfectly.. but last week the map photo urls give 403 error from cartocdn. Do you have any idea what the problem is exactly and how can we solve it?

Thanks in advance!

The map photo url, what lealfet js want to load: https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/14/7429/6860.png
and the response is:

Error 403 Forbidden

Forbidden

Guru Mediation:

Details: cache-hhn4057-HHN 1617106501 3254027811

Varnish cache server

Comment: I guess you've read https://carto.com/basemaps/ ?

Comment: Ohh.. i see the problem. On the Leaflet site, there is no info about any external dependency. But as i see, the cartocdn is a only limited free package. 
Ok.. thanks for the answer!